# Argument cannot be negative (function: open)

Tags: c, file-io

I write function to prevent run two instances of application with the same configuration (fifo file):

```
if( !filename_specified ) {
    char *fifofile = get_fifo_filename( config_get_uid( ct ) );
    int fifofd;

    if( !fifofile ) {
        lfprintf( stderr, _("%s: Cannot allocate memory.\n"), argv[ 0 ] );
        return 0;
    }

    /* negative_return_fn: Function "open(fifofile, 2049)" returns a negative number */
    fifofd = open( fifofile, O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK );
    if( fifofd >= 0 ) {
        lfprintf( stderr, _("Cannot run two instances of application with the same configuration.\n") );
        close( fifofd );
        return 0;
    }
    /* negative_returns: "fifofd" is passed to a parameter that cannot be negative */
    close( fifofd );
}
```

My code get this warning:

Negative value used as argument to a function expecting a positive value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [`open()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) returned a negative value it failed. If `open()` failed the value returned isn't a valid file descriptor, the file had not been opened, so it <strike>does not need to</strike> must not be `close()`ed.

Fix this by only passing `fifofd` to `close()` if it is greater or equal `0`, that is the corresponding call to `open()` succeeded:

```
if (0 <= fifofd)
{
  if (-1 == close(fifofd))
  {
    perror("close() failed");
  }
}
```

Comment: +1.  Being picky, "does not need to be closed" may be clearer as "must not be closed"

Comment: @simonc: Thanks, corrected. I again did translat literally, nat taking into account my languages culture. This, however, is a diffferent story though.